# How to create 1200x900 iPad App Preview?

Tags: ios, imovie, app-preview

How can I record app preview for iPads? It should have 1200x900 resolution, but there is not such simulator in Xcode?

What do you think to record one for iPhone and then resize it to 1200x900? Unfortunately iMovie does not support resizing video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Quicktime**, a native app for MacOS, it will save your screen in a High Resolution, then you can use any App of Video Editing like iMovie (Final-Cut, Adobe Premiere, After Effect) to redesign your Preview!

[image]

In iMovie, Make sure you have the latest Version and Do: File --> New App Preview

[image]

Comment: any cheaper / free solution? I need just resize video?!

Comment: As of September 2014, Apple has updated iMovie so that if you select "New App Preview" and put Quicktime recorded footage from an iPad, it will be 900 x 1200 or 1200 x 900.

Comment: even if iPsd simulator has a 1024x768 resolution?

Comment: @János don't worry when you edit your app-preview in iMovie..you'll get the resolution you want...but Check if you have the latest iMovie update !

Comment: Such as this answer touches on the side topic, not directly related to the question asked: when recording the video in the first place, it'll probably be easier to record directly from the device. Which is also done in QuickTime. Attach your iOS 8 device, select 'New Movie Recording' then use the drop down next to the record button to switch to recording your device rather than through your computer's camera.

Comment: @Kingofmit you are right, I recorded a 1024x768 movie and iMovie offered to export / share it to 1200x900